# How can I add space between these words?

Tags: javascript

This is my block of code that I need help with. I have tried a non break space and just putting them in different lines. How can I space them out?

```
document.write( Kyrin.name, Kyrin.age, Kyrin.gender, Kyrin.favcolour, Kyrin.profession);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.write(`${Kyrin.name} ${Kyrin.age} ${Kyrin.gender} ${Kyrin.favcolour} ${Kyrin.profession}`);
```

Should work for you. This is using backticks to set up a template literal which allows you to use ${variable} to inject variables into a string. This then has spaces between the words (since there are spaces withing the `string`;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Alternatively, you could not use template literals and do something like...

```
var text = Kyrin.name+" "+Kyrin.age+" "+Kyrin.gender+" "+Kyrin.favcolour+" "+Kyrin.profession;
document.write(text);
```

Since we are concatenating the variables together with " " spaces between.

Comment: Thanks so... Much TSR it was a great idea I will test it now. Also do you do sololearn? Because I do my name is Shadow.I would appreciate if you would join so I can practice with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them all into an array, then use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to convert it to string with [`separator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#Parameters) space.

> <sub>Specifies a string to separate each pair of adjacent elements of the array</sub>

```js
var Kyrin = {
  name: 'name', age: 3, gender: 'female', favcolour: 'orange', profession: 'yada'
};
document.write( [Kyrin.name, Kyrin.age, Kyrin.gender, Kyrin.favcolour, Kyrin.profession].join(' '));
```